# в чем функция третьего входа и резистора в логическом элементе?

Tags: электроника

Добрый день. Объясните пожалуйста на пальцах в чем функция третьего входа и резистора в логическом элементе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Народу так нравится схема, что ни кто не реагирует на "оффтопичный" вопрос его закрытием:)

Comment: @Visman так очередь на закрытие переполнена, если статистика не врет, так что толку нет. Проще заминусовать и дождаться удаления духом, если реально хочется снести вопрос.

Comment: Видимо, вы притащили картинку с хабрапоста, почему бы там на месте не спросить?)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответствует тематике сайта.

Answer (score 2):

Основная функция резистора устранение наводок(Ноль будет мерцанием, а не выключением). А входа вероятно, чтобы было понятнее где земля, туда подают минус(GND).